# Unescape HTML entities containing newline in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

If you have a string containing HTML entities and want to unescape it, this solution (or variants thereof) is suggested multiple times:

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

htmlDecode("&lt;img src='myimage.jpg'&gt;"); 
// returns "<img src='myimage.jpg'>"
```

(See, for example, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912522/1199564)

This works fine as long as the string does *not* contain newline and we are *not* running on Internet Explorer version pre 10 (tested on version 9 and 8).

If the string contains a newline, IE 8 and 9 will replace it with a space character instead of leaving it unchanged (as it is on Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE 10).

```
htmlDecode("Hello\nWorld"); 
// returns "Hello World" on IE 8 and 9
```

Any suggestions for a solution that works with IE before version 10?

Comment: What do you want to do with newline? remove it?

Comment: I want to keep it unchanged. I'll add an example.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will do exactly what you need, but have you checked out this [HTML encoding and decoding javascript library](http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple, but probably not the most efficient solution is to have `htmlDecode()` act only on character and entity references:

```
var s = "foo\n&amp;\nbar";
s = s.replace(/(&[^;]+;)+/g, htmlDecode);
```

More efficient is using an optimized rewrite of `htmlDecode()` that is only called once per input, acts only on character and entity references, and reuses the DOM element object:

```
function htmlDecode (input)
{
  var e = document.createElement("span");

  var result = input.replace(/(&[^;]+;)+/g, function (match) {
    e.innerHTML = match;
    return e.firstChild.nodeValue;
  });

  return result;
}

/* returns "foo\n&\nbar" */
htmlDecode("foo\n&amp;\nbar");
```

*Wladimir Palant has pointed out an XSS issue with this function: [The value of some (HTML5) event listener attributes, like `onerror`, is executed if you assign **HTML with elements that have those attributes specified** to the `innerHTML` property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations) So you should not use this function on arbitrary input containing actual HTML, only on HTML that is already escaped. Otherwise you should adapt the regular expression accordingly, for example use `/(&[^;<>]+;)+/` instead to prevent `&…;` where `…` contains tags from being matched.*

*For arbitrary HTML, please see his [alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434/785541), but note that it is not as compatible as this one.*

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm. I would suggest you edit the sample string "foo &amp; bar" to include "\n" characters like this "foo\n&amp;\nbar" to illustrate that the code handles newlines correctly. Also, could you please explain why 'e' is involved in a circular reference.

Comment: Makes sense. I would like to accept your edit to give you the credit, but I do not know how as it is the first time someone edited one of my answers. I can only see two spurious(?) rejects and no "Accept" button :-/

Comment: @mgd Apparently one cannot approve already rejected edits, so I have applied your edit and +1 for the comment.

Comment: Why is `e` a circular reference? It's used in the anonymous function but when the code returns, references to both are forgotten, so GC should be happy :-/

Comment: @PointedEars My edit might have been rejected because I had forgotten to insert a change comment. (embarrassing)

Comment: @AaronDigulla I see that the anon function references `e` but I don't see where the circularity is. If `a` references `b` which references `a` we have a circular reference. But why in this case? And why does it help to `null` `e` which goes out of scope right after the function returns?

Comment: Circular reference (CMIIW): `e` → `e.ownerDocument` → (`e.ownerDocument.defaultView` === `window`) → `window.htmlDecode` → `window.htmlDecode.[[Scope]]` → `e`. The problem is that (older) JScript's GC cannot clean that up even though `e` goes out of scope. See also: [Understanding and Solving Internet Explorer Leak Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: @AaronDigulla You are welcome. And thank you for your edit, I have adapted it only slightly.

Comment: @PointedEars: Consider this illegally encoded string `var s = "x\n&amp\ny\n&amp;\nz";`. The pattern your algorithm uses will match from the first `&` to the last `;` which means it will include two `\n` characters and will not work correctly on IE 8 and 9. Changing the pattern to `/(&[^&;]+;)+/g`will make it match from the last `&`. Now it works again on IE 8 and 9. However, on (at least) Chrome `&amp\n` is normally incorrectly (?) unescaped to `&` whereas this algorithm using the new pattern will leave it untouched which I guess is correct. I would suggest changing the pattern in your answer.

Comment: @PointedEars: Tried to make an edit to the question changing the pattern (two locations) and adding an example `"foo\n&amp\nbar\n&amp;\nbaz"`at the end illustrating the point. Apparently, the edit has been rejected (at least it doesn't show up in my browser as it used to do until accepted).

Comment: @PointedEars: Regarding circular references, IMHO the circular chain is incorrect in this location: `window.htmlDecode` → `window.htmlDecode.[[Scope]]`. Every time the function is called a new scope is created and the reference goes from the scope to the function. Also, the closure (anon function capturing `e`) also goes out of scope when the function returns. Therefore, the `null`ing is not necessary.

Comment: @mgd Please substantiate your claim about `[[Scope]]`. I can see nothing in ECMA-262-5.1 §13.2.1 to suggest that. In fact, I think if it was as you suggest, closures would not work. I will look into `e` later.

Comment: @mgd You have to draw the line somewhere. This function is not intended to process invalid markup, and I will not update it or approve changes to it so that it can (it was not me who rejected your edits, though). Feel free to do that in your code, and carefully consider the complexities before. However, according to [SGML](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SGML/productions.html#prod59), entity references are terminated either by `;` or RE. And at least for HTML 4.01, [`RE` is defined to be what is matched by `/\r/`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/HTML4.decl). So I have updated the expression accordingly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17232/discussion-between-mgd-and-pointedears)

Comment: Please consider restricting the characters accepted by your regular expression so that it won't match HTML tags, e.g. `/(&[^;<>\s]+;)+/`. Then your `htmlDecode` function will be safe to use even on unsafe input, something that cannot be said about the original function (see [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434/785541)).

Comment: @WladimirPalant Thank you for bringing the XSS issue to my attention. I consider this a security bug in DOM implementations: No client-side script code should be executed before the element has been added to the document tree. However, although markup like `&<img src="foo" alt="" onerror="window.alert(42)">;` is Valid HTML_5_ (but _not_ Valid HTML _4.01_), it is an extreme edge case. Ignoring HTML tags to consider that then, would defeat the purpose of the function. And I am not ready to build a full HTML parser into it. So, after careful consideration, I have to reject your suggestion.

Comment: @WladimirPalant I have added a caveat instead. If one has the choice, one should prefer the approach you present in your answer instead.